# Find string in two field with SQL

Tags: php, sql

I'm working on a search module, like facebook when you look for a friend.

So, i have in my table user two fields : `firstname` and `name`.

If i have for example a user : `firstname : Georges` and `name : Clooney`, i want, when i write :

- Geo...
- Cloo...
- loo geor...
- geor ney
- etc....

retrieve this user.

How can i do that with SQL ? I want to write a very permissive search module..

Comment: The `LIKE` condition.

Comment: have you tried anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will surely help you

Well the below method first calculate all possible combination of the possible words & then matches it with database

```
     <?php


        $name ='Georges Clooney'; // you search string
        $words=explode(" ", $name);;

        function get_all_combination($arr, $temp_string, &$collect) {
            if ($temp_string != "") 
                $collect []= $temp_string;

            for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($arr);$i++) {
                $arrcopy = $arr;
                $elem = array_splice($arrcopy, $i, 1); // removes and returns the i'th element
                if (sizeof($arrcopy) > 0) {
                    get_all_combination($arrcopy, $temp_string ." " . $elem[0], $collect);
                } else {
                    $collect []= $temp_string. " " . $elem[0];
                }   
            }   
        }

        $collect = array();
        get_all_combination($words, "", $collect);


           /* 
            $collect now have all possible combination of search string

            Array
            (
                [0] =>  Georges
                [1] =>  Georges Clooney
                [2] =>  Clooney
                [3] =>  Clooney Georges
            )
            */

        $sql="SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE (firstname like '%".implode("%' OR firstname  like '%",$collect)."%' or name  like '%".implode("%' OR name like '%",$collect)."%')" ;






        ?>
```

For any more help do ask

Comment: Your function get_all_combination is very good, but the query does not work at all...

Comment: could your print the query so that i can see what the error is , it worked for me,  adjust a bit according to your table

Answer (score 1):

What you need, is this little Friend: `%`

`WHERE  firstname LIKE '%" . $name . "%' OR name LIKE '%" . $name  ."%'`

Here is a tutorial:

http://www.webreference.com/programming/php/search/index.html

Comment: Then you should check the string before passing it to MySQL!

Comment: @ClémentAndraud `geor ney` is not LIKE `George Clooney`. `geor` would be, so would `ney`. The words together wouldn't match... The words apart would match... Think about it, and do at least some of the work yourself

Comment: Yeah, so, i don't want a simple like ;)

Comment: Then: as I said, check the string, if there are any spaces, if you, you could explode the string and pass it with another argument to your SQL Query ... Come on, it's not that hard ;-)

Comment: @ClémentAndraud So it looks like you didn't want the answer to `How can I do that with SQL?`, but rather, `Can someone do this for me in SQL?`

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
Select * from User where `name` LIKE '%search_string%' OR `firstname`
 LIKE '%search_string%' OR CONCAT(firstname,' ',name) LIKE '%search_string'%'
```

Comment: Yeah, i want something like your concat i think.. But this requet return nothing

Comment: Try This:                                                        Select * from User where `name` LIKE '%search_string%' OR `firstname`
 LIKE '%search_string%' OR ('firstname'+' '+'name') LIKE '%search_string'%'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM User
WHERE firstname LIKE '%'+@input+'%' OR name LIKE '%'+@input+'%'
```

where `@input` is the inserted text in the textbox.

Comment: I have a bug "division by zero" with that

Comment: What do you mean? I can't get you. Since we don't have a division, how you get a division by zero exception?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
   SELECT * from user 
   WHERE name LIKE '%search_string%'
   OR firstname LIKE '%search_string%'
```

It will match if any firstname or name containing search_string. it will show all users containing this string in name or first name.

Comment: `SELECT * from user 
   WHERE name LIKE '%geor ney%'
   OR firstname LIKE '%geor ney%'`   did you run this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try this

 select * from user where `name` like '%trim(search_string)%' OR `firstname`
 like '%trim(search_string)%' OR CONCAT(firstname,' ',name) LIKE '%".trim(search_string)."%';
```

Also concat both the fields and try to match.